# Google Search Console shows "Disallowed attribute or attribute value present in HTML tag " for <amp-img layout="fixed"

Tags: html, frontend, amp-html, magento-2.3, google-search-console

I don't understand why the layout="fixed" is an disallowed attribute value. Could anyone please help find a solution to this error being shown for several pages across our Magento store?

```
<amp-img layout="fixed" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" class="lazy lazy-loading lazy-blur p1only" name="NewportHotHero" data-src="/images/5b22c63cd95b2.jpg" width="1500" id="NewportHotHero" height="1"></amp-img></a>
```

The actual content for this category in the Magento Admin is as follows:

```
<p><a href="#products"><img id="NewportHotHero" class="p1only" style="display: none;" src="/images/5b22c63cd95b2.jpg" width="1500" name="NewportHotHero" border="0" /></a> <a name="pro_d"></a></p>
```

Comment: why do you have two source? and what is `data-src=` - is that documented on AMP? what happens when you remove `data-src=` ?

Comment: Hi, I really don't know what `data-src=` is, and also not sure where to locate this AMP page so that I can remove data-src=?

Comment: IMHO you need to clean the statement to be AMP-valid. Otherwise the error will persist.

Comment: Please enlighten me on how to go about cleaning the statement. Where exactly do I need to start with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your all attribute looks right, except `name="NewportHotHero"`.

The

> "name"

attribute is not documented in  [documentation](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-img/?referrer=ampproject.org#attributes).

Or you can play your code posted [here](https://playground.amp.dev/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fpreview.amp.dev%2Fdocumentation%2Fexamples%2Fcomponents%2Famp-img&format=websites&_gl=1*1k2rah0*_ga*YW1wLS14X2YxeGF3M2ZjN0tzLTNIZ21YU3c.) and see the error.

Comment: Thanks Desh. So you say that the `name` attribute is never allowed for amp-img?

Comment: Yes That's right. There seems no other error in your <amp-img> code

Comment: What should I do to only remove the name attribute from the AMP page? I can only edit the original content present in Magento Admin Catalog->Categories->Categoryname->Content. This is what I find there `<p><a href="#products"><img id="NewportHotHero" class="p1only" style="display: none;" src="/images/5b22c63cd95b2.jpg" width="1500" name="NewportHotHero" border="0" /></a> <a name="pro_d"></a></p>`

Comment: All the AMP errors are now fixed by removing the `name` attribute. Thanks for the help. Desh